# How to get a Google Colab cell output using my own Python program

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have no experience with Google Colab, yet I have a python program that I run on my computer but needs to use an algorithm that runs in Google Colab. If it is possible, how should my program call my algorithm from Google Colab and get its output?

Comment: Could you add more details of the algorithm you are using?

Comment: the algorithm is text to speech algorithm that its output is creating a wave file.  I want to send a text to the colab(or something like that) run the cells and download that wave file.